# Yahoo Weather API implementation in Webform Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2013

So I was trying to follow this video  [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6aie_vXFog) and implement the Yahoo! weather API (XML) into my webform project in Visual Basic 2013 pro.

But I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` error when I run the project in debug mode.

Here is the screenshots-

[image]
[image]
[image]

And the code block I'm having problem with-

```
 private void Getweather()
    {
        string query = String.Format("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=44418");
        XmlDocument wData = new XmlDocument();
        wData.Load(query);

        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(wData.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");
        XmlNode channel = wData.SelectSingleNode("rss").SelectSingleNode("channel");
        XmlNodeList nodes = wData.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item/yweather:forecast", manager);

        Temperature = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["temp"].Value;
        Condition = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;
        Humidity = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["hunidity"].Value;
        Windspeed = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:wind", manager).Attributes["speed"].Value;
        Town = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:city", manager).Attributes["city"].Value;
        TFCond = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;
        TFHigh = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["high"].Value;
        TFLow = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["Low"].Value;


    }
```

And I'm trying to call this method in a button click event using-

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Getweather();
        textBox1.Text = Town;
        textBox2.Text = Temperature;
        textBox3.Text = Condition;
        textBox4.Text = Humidity;
        textBox5.Text = Windspeed;
        textBox6.Text = TFCond;
        textBox7.Text = TFHigh;
        textBox8.Text = TFLow;
    }
```

And finally the [API](http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=44418)

Pretty new to coding .. help appreciated! :)

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line that is throwing the exception and see  what's null. It's probably `.SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager)`

Comment: @PoweredByOrange thanks... it is! but how do I fix this? any ideas?

Comment: I think you've missed the 2nd SelectSingleNode part for the Condition variable in getWeather(). Look your linked vid again

Comment: @envyM6 Try `channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["text"].Value` You're missing the `Item` node.

Comment: Any suggestion how to modify this code to enter the location manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
       Condition = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;
```

Has to be

```
       Condition = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;
```